# batch file: if %variable% (commands)

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, environment-variables, conditional-statements

i want to use my %variable% to manage the conditional clauses in a IF.. THEN.. ELSE in a batch file.
Something like the following:

```
set variable=%%homedrive%% EQU C:
if %variable% (
   echo test ok
   ) else (
   echo test fail
   )
```

if i write on a cmd console:

```
set test=1 equ 1
if %test% echo OK
```

it works!

i'll use it in a for /f cicle:
this is my pseudo codethis is my pseudo code to correct

```
(
 rem echo "%systemdrive%;;"
 echo "%%COMPUTERNAME%% EQU [x];[some parameters1]"
 echo "%%USERNAME%% NEQ [y];[some parameters2]"
 echo "%%LOGONSERVER%% EQU [z];[some parameters3]"
 [..]
) > "%temp%\CSG_fs.tmp"
[..]
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-2* delims=;" %%a in ("%temp%\CSG_fs.tmp") do (
    set cond=%%a& set cond=!cond:~1!
    set parm=%%b& set parm=!parm:~0,-1!
    echo   -   cicle: "!cond!" --^> "!parm!" 
    call if !cond! call:CSG_sub_fs !parm!
    echo    -  done
    )
goto:eof
:CSG_sub_fs
[..]
goto:eof
```

--edit--

how can i use the variable !cond! to decide if execute the call to CSG_sub_fs?

```
call if !cond! call:CSG_sub_fs !parm!
```

does not work because it returns: "Can not find the batch label specified - IF"

and if i use

```
if !cond! call:CSG_sub_fs !parm!
```

it will say: "call:CSG_sub_fs not expected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - there doesn't seem to be a question, so it's not that easy to answer.

You have a problem with

```
echo "^%COMPUTERNAME^% EQU [x];[some parameters1]"
```

because `^` does not escape `%` - `%` escapes `%` - use `%%COMPUTERNAME%%...`

(you should have been able to check this just by `TYPE`ing "%temp%\CSG_fs.tmp"

Next problem is that

```
for /f "tokens=1-2* delims=; usebackq" %%a in (%temp%\CSG_fs.tmp) do (
```

may process the file `%temp%\CSG_fs.tmp` provided `%temp%\CSG_fs.tmp` contains no spaces, semicolons or commas. If it contains any of these deafult separators, or certain other characters with a special meaning, then you must enclose the filename in double-quotes `"%temp%\CSG_fs.tmp"`and use the `usebackq` option.

You've attempted to use `usebackq` but `DELIMS` must be the `LAST` option if it is used. Your code would set "`;`","","`u`","`s`","`e`","`b`","`a`","`c`","`k`" and "`q`" as delimiters.

Beyond that, perhaps if you explain what you intend to achieve, we'd be able to devise the appropriate code.

---

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CLS

REM I'm setting these variables for testing.
REM That isn't ususally a good idea but the SETLOCAL
REM will ensure they are restored on exit

SET computername=[x]
SET logonserver=[z]


(
 rem echo "%systemdrive%;;"
 echo "%%COMPUTERNAME%% EQU [x];[some parameters1]"
 echo "%%USERNAME%% NEQ [y];[some parameters2]"
 echo "%%LOGONSERVER%% EQU [z];[some parameters3]"
) > "%temp%\CSG_fs.tmp"
for /f "usebackqtokens=1-2* delims=;" %%a in ("%temp%\CSG_fs.tmp") do (
    set cond=%%a& set "cond=IF !cond:~1! CALL :csg_sub_fs "
    set parm=%%b& set parm=!parm:~0,-1!
    CALL :varcmd "!cond!" "!parm!"
    )
GOTO :eof

:varcmd
%~1 %~2
GOTO :eof

:csg_sub_fs
ECHO parameters supplied to csg_sub_fs were: %*
GOTO :eof
```

I've forced the variablenames to match the conditions you've used in order to trigger the subroutine calls. Change as you need to prove your concept.

And dont worry about imperfect English. I'm sure I wouldn't do as well in your language!

Comment: thanks, i've corrected my code and i ve added my question :) sorry for my bad english!